# Using the model builder in ArcGIS, how do I iterate through rasters in a model?

Tags: modelbuilder, iterator

Right now I'm attempting to iterate through rasters collected in a file geodatabase, in a model that I've created using the model builder in ArcGIS. I don't have the ModelBuilder Toolbox, otherwise this would be a lot simpler to do.

Is there a way (without using the Iterate Rasters tool) that I can loop through the rasters in a gdb?

Thanks,
 Renee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Evidently I was proceeding from the wrong assumption. The ModelBuilder Toolbox is not something that I would add in.  I just needed to select "Insert", "Iterators" and "Rasters" in the model builder window.